# XSLT current template mode?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have one simple question in xslt 2.0. Is there any way of obtaining the mode inside a template. I want to read the mode and compare with a value. This is because i require to use same template for different computations. There is a variable whose value is depending on mode.

Currently i am passing  to solve this problem. If there is a way we can get the current mode of template, it will be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, XSLT 2.0 doesn't provide a function to find out the current mode name. You can however use e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>` to apply templates in the current mode.

If you want the mode as a name, then Saxon 9 provides it with an extension function http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/current-mode-name.html.